# Weird syntax error in using beautifulsoup.find()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This may be entirely obvious, but I'm stumped (kinda new to python, sorry):

```
page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.somerandompage.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
currentDate = soup.find("span", class="posted-on")
```

I'm looking for the following element in the page:

```
<span class="posted-on">Posted on Friday, <br/>August 12th, 2011</span>
```

I'm getting this syntax error instead:

```
"test.py", line 22
currentDate = soup.find("span", class="posted-on")
                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The basic documentation online seems identical to me (obviously assuming find_parents() and find() work much the same way):

```
a_string.find_parent("p")
# <p class="story">Once upon a time there were three little sisters; and their names were
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a> and
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>;
#  and they lived at the bottom of a well.</p>

a_string.find_parents("p", class="title")
# []
```

So what am I doing wrong?  I know class is a reserved Python keyword; is that what's messing this up somehow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use `class` as a keyword argument. Use `{'class': 'posted-on'}` instead:

```
currentDate = soup.find('span', {'class': 'posted-on'})
```

Alternatively, bs4 supports a [`class_` spelling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) too:

```
currentDate = soup.find('span', class_='posted-on')
```

Comment: So, the documentation is wrong then, correct?  Specifically the example in this section: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-parents-and-find-parent

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And here I thought I was going crazy. Of course you are correct, thanks very much.  Marking as answered as soon as it allows me (feeling dumb about posting in the first place, tbh).